# React.JS - Child Componenet Not Updating When Recieving Props (Function Components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I have a higher order functional component in my app that passes JSON to it's child component. I am using react Hooks to manage state. I can't use componentDidUpdate since this is not a class component.

I'm using `useEffect()` to get it to process the JSON on initial render, but after that I can't seem to get it to update. I've confirmed the PROPS are indeed changing and the JSON is unique (it changes on the click of a button).

Here is my code:

```
function FormSection(props) {
    const [questions, updateQuestions] = useState([]);
    const [sectionJSON, updateSectionJSON] = useState(props.json);

    const fetchQuestionsData = json => {
       /* API CALL TRANSFORM JSON INTO HTML FOR USE ELSEWHERE IN THE APP */
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchQuestionsData(sectionJSON);
    }, [sectionJSON]);

    ...

}
```

I've also tried changing the `useEffect()` hook to use props directly:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchQuestionsData(props.json);
    }, [props.json]);
```

The parent componenet is calling it as follows:

```
    <FormSection key={i} json={newJSON} />
```

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Does the fetchQuestionsData function call updateSectionJSON()?  I'm assuming it does...

Comment: No it doesn't, the `props.json` is passed to `fetchQuestionData()` to essentially create a new view. It renders HTML (and other data) that is used elsewhere. I'll update the question.

Comment: `FormSection` will only rerender if it receives props or if something in the dependency array of the `useEffect` changes.  So unless the downstream effects that you describe are cascading back down to this component in the form of new props, it won't update.  Based on the naming of the function, I actually would have expected it would call `updateQuestions()`... and that totally would cause it to rerender.

Comment: Sorry just rereading that props.json is changing... but is props.json an object?  The object reference could still be the same even though the contents are changing... just like `const foo = {}; foo.bar = "baz";` does not throw an error because you aren't reassigning the object.  Just a guess...

Comment: So `newJSON` is a global state set in the React Context API. So there is a button I click to "add a question" and this adds a value to an array inside the `newJSON` object. I need the app to re-render with this additional question. So this `<FormSection />` doesn't update the JSON, but another componenet updates the Global state which then should re-render this Component. Make sense?

Comment: So I figured out the issue, but I don't have a solution. It turns out mutating a JSON object stored in state doesn't trigger the state change. I may have to build each object of the JSON as state variables... but this is almost impossible.

Comment: Could you just do something like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.json))`?

Answer (score 3):

When you set,

```
const [sectionJSON, updateSectionJSON] = useState(props.json);
```

is equivalent to,

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      sectionJSON: props.json
   }
}
```

So your `sectionJSON` will set only once and any subsequent change in `props.json` will not change `sectionJSON`.

So this will execute only once, and not when `props.json` changes

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuestionsData(sectionJSON);
}, [sectionJSON]);
```

To make this work you need to pass `props.json` to your `useEffect` hook as,

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetchQuestionsData(props.json);
}, [props.json]);
```

Doing this will not re-render your component, because your component's `state` is not changing, like we do using `componentDidUpdate` in class based component, so you should set your state in `fetchQuestionsData` like,

```
const fetchQuestionsData = json => {
   /* API CALL TRANSFORM JSON INTO HTML FOR USE ELSEWHERE IN THE APP */
   updateSectionJSON(json);   //This will re-render your component.
};
```

Comment: I tried this but adding `updateSectionJSON(json);` to the `fetchQuestionsData` doesn't trigger the update. I also tried setting `useEffect` to use `props.json` and that doesn't work either. It may be something deeper then then. I'll review tomorrow. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post what is inside of fetchQuestionsData  function